# Move the entire folder into new directory if it contains a file

Tags: shell, unix, grep, cd

I have a directory

test2 with following contents :

```
file1
  test.pdb
  xyz.txt
  1.txt

file2
  test.pdb
  xyz.txt

file3
  test.pdb
  xyz.txt 
  1.txt
```

I want to move the folder(here, file 1 and file 3) which contain 1.txt to a new directory named 'complete'.How to do it?

Desired output :

complete

```
file1
  test.pdb
  xyz.txt
  1.txt

file3
  test.pdb
  xyz.txt 
  1.txt
```

test2

```
file2
  test.pdb
  xyz.txt
```

Code till now :

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name "*ionized.pdb" -print| sed "s|^\./||"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using `bash` you can use this command from **parent directory of `test2/`**:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' d; do
   [[ -f $d/1.txt ]] && echo mv "$d" complete
done < <(find test2 -type d -print0)
```

Once satisfied with output, you can remove `echo` before `mv` in above command.

If not using `bash` then use this pipeline:

```
find test2 -type d -print0 |
while IFS= read -rd '' d; do [ -f "$d/1.txt" ] && echo mv "$d" complete; done
```

This assumes both directories `test2` and `complete` are at same level.

Comment: Thanks.is the code assuming complete directory exists inside test2 or outside?

Comment: Code assumes `complete2` is inside `test2`. If it is outside then code will be further simplified

Comment: I am seeing this output mv ./file1 complete
mv ./file3 complete

But complete file is empty..